# How to Change URL and port of Gulp server ?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I've a application in angularjs and using gulp server it's running on port like :

http://localhost:3000/

I want to run this without port like :

http://example.com/

I've following code snippet in Gulp/Server.js which is :

```
var routes = null;
if ( baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1) )
{
    routes = {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
    };
}

var server = {
    baseDir: baseDir,
    routes : routes
};

browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    ghostMode : false,
    //server   : server,
    browser  : browser
    proxy    : "http://example.com/"  
});
```

but when I tried it goes on

http://example.com:3000

Please suggest.

Thanks